# MongoDB mongorestore non-sharded collection to sharded collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

I have 2 MongoDB collections on 2 different database. DB1-Collection1 is non-sharded, DB2-Collection2 is sharded. I use following command to dump DB1-Collection1.

```
mongodump --host some_ip:27017 --username some_user --password some_pwd --authenticationDatabase admin --db DB1 --collection col1 --gzip --archive=/root/col1.gz --quiet
```

Just before I run mongorestore command to restore data to DB2-Collection2, I saw this article,

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/

which says

> Starting in MongoDB 4.2, mongodump and mongorestore cannot be part of
>   a backup strategy for sharded clusters. These manual tools do not
>   maintain the atomicity guarantees of transactions across shards.

DB2 is running MongoDB 4.2, and Collection2 is sharded. Will it be OK if I run mongorestore to restore the data, or what's the proper way to restore data in that case.